# JsonConverter VBA, импорт и вывод значений из JSON при количестве строк JSON больше одной

Tags: vba, ms-access

Подскажите пожалуйста, тестирую модуль JsonConverter , не могу перескочить на следующее выражение Json. Сайт выводит Json данные из одной таблицы, все норм. Формат вывода JSON следующий:

**{"good_id":"1","good_name":"яблоки","price":"0.15","delivery_date":"2005-07-06"}{"good_id":"2","good_name":"Груши","price":"0.25","delivery_date":"2005-08-07"}
{"good_id":"4","good_name":"Велосипед","price":"25.48","delivery_date":"2018-08-07"}**

Вывод JSON прекрасно работает. А также удается спарсить одну первую строку в VBA. Но никак получается вывести последовательно значения каждой из строк. Вот код, помогите пожалуйста. Не могу докрутить цикл правильно в JSON.

```
...
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim URL As String
Dim user As String
Dim password As String
If IsNull(Me.f_login) Or IsNull(Me.f_password) Then
MsgBox "Заполните все поля логин /пароль!"
Exit Sub
End If
user = Me.f_login
password = Me.f_password
argumentString = "user=" & user & "&password=" & password
'MsgBox argumentString
On Error GoTo 10
URL = "http://localhost/json_test/index.php"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
xmlhttp.send argumentString
MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)

'с этого момента начались эксперименты и проблемы
Dim JSON As Dictionary
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.responseText)
For Each Keys In JSON
MsgBox JSON("good_name")
Next Keys
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Формат JSON неверный. Должно быть так:

```
[
  {"good_id":"1","good_name":"яблоки","price":"0.15","delivery_date":"2005-07-06"},
  {"good_id":"2","good_name":"Груши","price":"0.25","delivery_date":"2005-08-07"},
  {"good_id":"4","good_name":"Велосипед","price":"25.48","delivery_date":"2018-08-07"}
]
```

Тогда его можно будет обработать как массив об'ектов.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, сейчас попробую переписать пару строк на стороне сервера в PHP.